# JAMS.dll Failed to resolve type reference [Acumatica] 2020 R1

Tags: c#, acumatica

I am trying to Publish Manufacturing 20.117.0016.0076 and I receive this error

```
JAMS.dll Failed to resolve type reference: PX.Objects.Common.MultiDuplicatesSearchEngine`1 declared in PX.Objects, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null
JAMS.dll Failed to resolve type reference: PX.Objects.Common.DuplicatesSearchEngineBase`1 declared in PX.Objects, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null
JAMS.dll Failed to resolve method reference: System.Void PX.Objects.Common.MultiDuplicatesSearchEngine`1<JAMS.MRP.AMForecast>::.ctor(PX.Data.PXCache,System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1<System.Type>,System.Collections.Generic.ICollection`1<!0>) declared in PX.Objects, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null
JAMS.dll Failed to resolve method reference: !0 PX.Objects.Common.DuplicatesSearchEngineBase`1<JAMS.MRP.AMForecast>::Find(System.Collections.IDictionary) declared in PX.Objects, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null
JAMS.dll Failed to resolve method reference: System.Boolean PX.Objects.Common.MultiDuplicatesSearchEngine`1<JAMS.MRP.AMForecast>::RemoveItem(!0) declared in PX.Objects, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null
JAMS.dll Failed to resolve method reference: System.Void PX.Objects.Common.MultiDuplicatesSearchEngine`1<JAMS.MRP.AMMPS>::.ctor(PX.Data.PXCache,System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1<System.Type>,System.Collections.Generic.ICollection`1<!0>) declared in PX.Objects, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null
JAMS.dll Failed to resolve method reference: !0 PX.Objects.Common.DuplicatesSearchEngineBase`1<JAMS.MRP.AMMPS>::Find(System.Collections.IDictionary) declared in PX.Objects, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null
JAMS.dll Failed to resolve method reference: System.Boolean PX.Objects.Common.MultiDuplicatesSearchEngine`1<JAMS.MRP.AMMPS>::RemoveItem(!0) declared in PX.Objects, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null
Validation failed.
Open Visual Studio
```

Comment: Check version of Acumatica assembly in your website Bin directory. 
 What version is it? ex from traces: "PX.Objects, Version=1.0.0.0"

Comment: To summarize my problem Where using Acumatica 20.100.0095 and trying to Upgrade to Acumatica 20.2 during the upgrade I am receiving Error 'int is incompatible with uniqueidentifier' and I saw upgrade notes in Acumatica Community that why Im trying to Publish Manufacturing  . Maybe I published a wrong version of Manufacturing. Where using Acumatica 20.100.0095 and I dont know what version of Manufacturing to publish.

Comment: I suspect a version mismatch error too. That's why I suggested looking up file version. You need to check Major+Minor build number 20.1, 20.2, 21.1...

Comment: Also I believe update procedure is to unpublish all customization before update.

Comment: This should be minimum compatible version which is higher than what you are using: http://acumatica-builds.s3.amazonaws.com/index.html?prefix=builds/20.1/20.117.0016/

Comment: when we upgrade to Acumatica ERP 20.100.0095 we did not upgrade our Manufacturing
Is it required to upgrade manufacturing before upgrading to 2020 R2 or 2021 R1?

Comment: Upgrade notes says that I need to update Manufacturing Edition customization package so 
I tried to upgrade Acumatica to 20.117.0016.0076 and publish manufacturing 20.117.0016.0076? and this is the error I receive after publish
`-41 Sql#Upgrade2018R2MSSQL
Column name 'CompanyID' does not exist in the target table or view.
Could not create constraint or index. See previous errors.
Invalid column name 'CompanyID'.
Invalid column name 'CompanyID'.
Invalid column name 'CompanyID'.
FAILED TO INSERT BOM OPER REV RECORDS
Query in question:
 /**** Update: 2019.11.08 ****/ ... `

Answer (score 0):

Do a publish with the cleanup- it will reprocess the Scripts and DLL files. Perhaps will then add in the CompanyID (typically a standard column on an Acumatica table)